# Allow HTML tags in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, design

If "<i>" is innocuous enough to be allowed in questions and answers, why can't we use it in comments too? Please don't make me memorize a bunch of dippy Markdown syntax just to add a little flavor to my comments.

Comment: Dippy markdown? Theres `**` for bold and `*` for italics, which I would take over `<i>` and `<b>` anyday.

Comment: See, right there I have to remember which is which. If I'm going to commit that to memory it's probably going to come at the cost of forgetting something else, like the capital of Sri Lanka.

Comment: Agree with @Ian

Comment: @Ian, @Alex: That would be a bit more helpful if there was preview so you could check that you'd gotten it straight *before* posting.

Comment: @SamB preview for comments seems a bit much.

Comment: [Subscript and superscript would not hurt.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/subscript-and-superscript-in-comments-fail)

Comment: @phenry the capital of Sri Lanka is [Sri Jayawardenepura Kotte](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/what-is-the-capital-of-sri-lanka.html) (JIC you forgot).

Answer (score 30):

We do allow very limited markdown in comments now. **Click the "help" link below the Add Comment button to get comment formatting help**.

- `*` and `_` for  bold, italic
- `` for code blocks
- `[example](http://example.com "merely an example")`

No HTML, just Markdown in comments, please!

See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#comment-formatting

Comment: Also, on sites that support it (e.g., [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com), [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com)) you can use MathJaX in comments, for example `$\sin^2 \theta$`..

Comment: How do you [write subscript and superscript](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1518/subscript-and-superscript-in-comments-fail) in Markdown ?

Comment: Italic with * does not always work.

Comment: Let's test : 4 π *r*². This fails !

Answer (score 7):

I think the idea of a comment should be a quick text entry.  If the comments start getting all jacked up with LI and IMG and all of the others, you lose all UI smoothness for the sake of better terms.

Overall, please no...

Comment: Subscript and superscript would not hurt.

Answer (score 3):

A markdown for links would be great and helpful, something like [A Search Engine](http://www.google.com)

Comment: We have that already for markdown. It just doesn't work in comments: [a search engine](http://duckduckgo.com/).

Comment: Though of course [it should](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments).

Comment: @bignose it does now!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'm just sick of having to remember to escape > and < in posts but not in comments.

Okay-- and I'd love to know how to escape asterisks because I've had to resort to using >smile< instead of my usual "asterisk" smile "asterisk"...  >sigh<

Comment: Comments are text. Text only!  No bold. No italics. Just text!  Let's just agree that we shouldnot need to escape anything. We can disagree on the reason that would be :).  I would hate escaping them too, just don't use them that way.

Comment: I'd like text-only comments. Some Markdown support got added to them sometime last week, I believe. I recall leaving a comment with some asterisks around a word (something I've done in text for years) and was surprised to see italics in my resulting comment. Or are you arguing that I shouldn't use underscores and asterisks in text in general?

Comment: well, probably they shouldn't have changed the syntax out from under the feet of existing, frozen comments, but oh well...