# Markdown URLs in comments?

Tags: feature-request, support, comments, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inline links in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments)

I posted a comment recently and wanted to include some URLs. To save space in the comment section I tried to markdown the URLs, except it just came up as "[link text]([shortenedurl.com/test....](http://www.longerurl.com/fullurl/files/relevantfile.html))".

Sorry if I've missed any earlier discussion on this topic, my search did not reveal anything this specific. Are there any other ways to include hyperlinks in comments, or does one just give the URL and let the comment formatter automatically link and shorten it?

Comment: Did you actually search? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments and here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments/

Comment: Yeah, I searched for `markdown`, `url`, `comments`.