# What markdown is allowed in comments?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Allow HTML tags in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments)
>   [How does the comment system and comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work)

Exactly what the title says, I know there's a question about this already I just can't find the sucker.

Comment: FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work/19757#19757

Comment: It's Jeff's answer on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments -- which is why it's hard to find. I actually went through Jeff's answers, sorted by "recent", because I knew he edited it around April 1st.

Comment: May be this should be part of the `[FAQ]` questions?

Comment: @json: I think the edits we made are probably sufficient (thanks, btw). This question will be closed, but should hang around so the question in the title is searchable.

Comment: @Jon: exactly, keeping this would make it possible to appear prominently when asking a new question and when searching and adding the FAQ tag would give it some officialness.

Comment: @json: To put `[faq]` on this question would require a reopen, a cleanup of both the question and your answer, an edit of the existing FAQ entry to break out that content (which, IMO, doesn't make sense)... I think it's enough to keep the existing FAQ entry updated, and maybe clean up this question a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

<sub><del>I believe this is a dupe</del> *[It is! It is a duppy quest!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Taw_a_Putty_Tat)*, but it's:</sub>

- *Italics* `*Italics*` *Also* `_Also_`
- **Bold** `**Bold**` **Also** `__Also__`
- ***Bold italics are not allowed*** `***Bold italics are not allowed***`
- `Code` `Code`
- [links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) `[links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ "Meta")`

For a more complete explanation, you can see [the relevant part of the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work/19757#19757).

Comment: Hmm... didn't know that. The FAQ should probably be updated.

Comment: I have updated the FAQ to reflect this.

Comment: @Jon, really, I had to upvote that comment. The irony is palpable.