# Comments don't have formatting tags or line breaks

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, markdown

I noticed that comments do not support formatting and line breaks like we have in posts.

The [markdown help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) doesn't seem to apply to the comments, so I think it is a bug.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work

Comment: possible duplicate of [What markdown is allowed in comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46642/what-markdown-is-allowed-in-comments)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Comments have no line breaks and generally no block-level formatting (such as extended blocks of code).

You can, however, use some of the same formatting that applies to normal posts:

- *Italics* `*Italics*` *Also* `_Also_`
- **Bold** `**Bold**` **Also** `__Also__`
- ***Bold italics are not allowed*** `***Bold italics are not allowed***`
- `Code` `Code`
- [links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) `[links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ "Meta")`

For a more complete explanation, you can see [the relevant part of the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work/19757#19757).

Comment: Note to add: The comment syntax is *superficially similar* to the one used in posts but differs in a number of headachy ways. You can hope never to encounter those cases, though :-)

Comment: Its sad whe cannot have even line breaks in comments :S

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: Wow, same thing happened to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50447

Comment: @ase69s,
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
Yeah, 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
You 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
cannot  
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
have 
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
it, unless you overflow it :)

Comment: @S.Mark: *̶T̶h̶a̶t̶s ̶g̶r̶e̶a̶t* ;-)

Comment: And I would hate to read comments if they all looked like that!!!!

Comment: @SMark stop breaking comments! Damn kinds with your fancy overflows!!

Comment: is
                                                                                             
this
                                                                                             
really
.............................................................................................
the
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
only
_____________________________________________________________________________________________
way?

Answer (score 4):

(Don't forget inline links!)

We do allow very limited markdown in comments now:

- `*` and `_` for  bold, italic
- `` for code blocks
- `[example](http://example.com "merely an example")`

No HTML, just Markdown in comments, please!

[Allow HTML tags in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments)

Comment: sorry but *why* not line-breaks? via double space?

Answer (score 2):

*Some* of the formatting works in comments. Notably inline links, **emphasis**, ****strong emphasis**** and `` `code` ``.

This is all I could find in reference: [a blog post about the changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/).