# Line breaks not working in comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)
>   [Stack Overflow comments don’t have formatting tags or line breaks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50444/stack-overflow-comments-dont-have-formatting-tags-or-line-breaks)

I've been struggling for some time with adding line breaks to comments on SO. I tried adding a double line break in the comment editor, as one would do in a question, but that didn't work. After reading the comment help, I tried adding two spaces after each line; still, to no avail. Am I doing something wrong here?

I'm including a comment with an attempted line break.

Comment: Here's one line  

Here's another

Comment: And of course: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757

Comment: Previously, it was possible to insert linebreaks in comment editor, but they don't appear as such after submitting. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form Right now, you've to use shift+enter for that (to separate your thoughts and so on).

Comment: I already use Shift+Return to add a line break in the comment editor, but it disappears without a trace when the comment is published.

Comment: *"but it disappears without a trace when the comment is published."* That is a good thing. Trust me on this. On a few sites there is a way to force the matter and it is hellishly distracting. Comments are *supposed* to be wimpy little things without much expressiveness.

Comment: Blah,                                                                                   
blah,                                                                                   
blah.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't add line breaks in comments, stop trying.

> After reading the comment help, I tried adding two spaces after each line; still, to no avail

There is nothing in the comments help saying it's possible.

> [**Comment formatting**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)
>
> **Comments support only bold, italic, code and links;** in addition, a few shorthand links are available.

Comment: [This page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks) begs to differ. Not to mention, I see comments around SO with line breaks all the time.

Comment: @JulesMazur, that page is for Q&A, not for comments, as they have a limited markup available. Regarding the examples, show me **one**...!

Comment: I've looked through some questions, and I'm no longer able to find any examples. But then, why write that a line break can be added by using two whitespaces on the page I liked to?

Comment: @JulesMazur, Are you just asking? read the answers you get!

Comment: @JulesMazur - it does add a line-break, *in a post*.  Line breaks don't work in comments, never have...they could get obnoxiously, vertically tall if we did allow it.  It's been discussed here on meta many times, and every time overwhelmingly shot down.

Comment: @NickCraver, Actually I think it was supported once, wasn't it? you could add markup to comments, or am I wrong?

Comment: Alright, thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: @gdoron - AFAIK it was never *supported*, that's not to say it wasn't *possible* at one point

Comment: @NickCraver maybe if you do the something like either ( up to 600 characters in comment OR up 5/6 lines of with any number of characters). By doing this you still restrict the number of lines but give users more formatting power

Comment: @asma22 There are many ways to exploit that, and you still have to consider the many-comments case where we have dozens in a section. I just can't see us supporting this. It also would produce unexpected behavior on existing mobile and API clients that have always known this to not work.

Comment: There are currently dozens of comments on a post, and **many** get folded. Your folding feature would still be effective on these. The pros of formatting outweigh the cons of a few. As for issues with mobile. I don't think that's a really good excuse, SO can kindly improve it's design or completely separate its mobile version from non-mobile clients.

Comment: @asma22 the mobile clients are applications we don't have direct control over.

Comment: I ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­­ ­ ­ ­­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­­ ­ ­ ­ ­ ­ tried, but I just couldn't find any workarounds.

Comment: There's                                                                                   
definitely                                                                                 
no                                                                                      
***good***                                                                                  
way...

Comment: Has this really not been fixed after six years??

Comment: @flarn2006 This is not a bug, its by design. I hate it, but its what it is.

Comment: @SleepProgger Source?

Comment: You can add a (large!) line break using `$$ $$` (an empty block formula),
but only if the StackExchange site supports MathJax.