# Is it possible to add line breaks in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've read through the comment formatting section on the [markdown help page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).  Adding line breaks to comments doesn't appear to be mentioned, and practice also leads me to believe that line breaks in comments are not possible.  But just in case I'm missing something:  is it possible to add line breaks to comments?

Answer (score 4):

In sites without Mathjax, [it's not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50444/comments-dont-have-formatting-tags-or-line-breaks) (hence the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) tag on that).

In sites with Mathjax enabled, you can use display style to achieve what you want. Enclose your text with `$$` and use `\text{some text}` command to achieve it.